# Create a dictionary from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

How can I convert the below `df` to a dictionary like mentioned in the output?

```
print (df)
  school_name student_name   address  phone
0         ABC         joey    london   5685
1         ABC       andrew   califor   5688
2         ABC        phill     los A   5687
3         DEF        joey1   london1  56858
4         DEF      andrew1  califor1  56878
5         DEF       phill1    los A1  56987
6         XYZ        joey2    autria   4455
7         XYZ       phill2    autria   6655
```

Need:

```
{'ABC': {'student_name': ['joey', 'andrew', 'phill'], 
         'address': ['london', 'califor', 'los A'], 
         'phone': [5685, 5688, 5687]}, 
 'DEF': {'student_name': ['joey1', 'andrew1', 'phill1'], 
         'address': ['london1', 'califor1', 'los A1'], 
         'phone': [56858, 56878, 56987]},
 'XYZ': {'student_name': ['joey2', 'phill2'],
         'address': ['autria', 'autria'], 
         'phone': [4455, 6655]}}
```

I tried using list comprehension followed by `groupby` but I didn't get the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for avoid lists fro column `school_name` if use custom lambda function in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), last convert `Series` to final ouput by [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = (df.set_index('school_name')
        .groupby('school_name')
        .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('list'))
        .to_dict())
print (d)
{'ABC': {'student_name': ['joey', 'andrew', 'phill'], 
         'address': ['london', 'califor', 'los A'], 
         'phone': [5685, 5688, 5687]}, 
 'DEF': {'student_name': ['joey1', 'andrew1', 'phill1'], 
         'address': ['london1', 'califor1', 'los A1'], 
         'phone': [56858, 56878, 56987]},
 'XYZ': {'student_name': ['joey2', 'phill2'],
         'address': ['autria', 'autria'], 
         'phone': [4455, 6655]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict comprehension on each school name:

```
out = {school: subdf.to_dict('list')
           for school, subdf in df.set_index('school_name').groupby(level=0)}
```

Output:

```
>>> out
{'ABC': {'student_name': ['joey', 'andrew', 'phill'],
  'address': ['london', 'califor', 'los A'],
  'phone': [5685, 5688, 5687]},
 'DEF': {'student_name': ['joey1', 'andrew1', 'phill1'],
  'address': ['london1', 'califor1', 'los A1'],
  'phone': [56858, 56878, 56987]},
 'XYZ': {'student_name': ['joey2', 'phill2'],
  'address': ['autria', 'autria'],
  'phone': [4455, 6655]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html?highlight=groupby%20agg#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg) with an *index-oriented* [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html?highlight=to_dict#pandas.DataFrame.to_dict) :

```
out = df.groupby("school_name").agg(list).to_dict("index")
```

Output :

```
{'ABC': {'student_name': ['joey', 'andrew', 'phill'],
  'address': ['london', 'califor', 'los A'],
  'phone': [5685, 5688, 5687]},
 'DEF': {'student_name': ['joey1', 'andrew1', 'phill1'],
  'address': ['london1', 'califor1', 'los A1'],
  'phone': [56858, 56878, 56987]},
 'XYZ': {'student_name': ['joey2', 'phill2'],
  'address': ['autria', 'autria'],
  'phone': [4455, 6655]}}
```